# Change Select Element To Div with additional componenets

Tags: jquery

I was about to create a basic jquery plugin (for educational and self learning purposes) and I just want to convert select element into div element whenever I call the function via jquery e.g $('.anyID').newdiv();

so this is how it supposed to be

From This :

```
<select id="anyID"><option value="">Default Text</option>
<option value="one">First</option>
<option value="two">Second</option>
<option value="three">Third</option>
<option value="four">Fourth</option>
<option value="five">Fifth</option>
</select>
```

Into This :

```
<div class="random class" id="anyID">
<div class="default text">Default Text</div>
<div class="content">
<div class="item" data-value="one">First</div>
<div class="item" data-value="two">Second</div>
<div class="item" data-value="three">Third</div>
<div class="item" data-value="four">Fourth</div>
<div class="item" data-value="five">Fifth</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is this possible?
Any help would really appreciated
Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var html=''
var firstOption='';
var remainingOptions='<div class="content">';
$('#anyID option').each(function(index,item){
  if(index>0){
    remainingOptions+='<div class="default text">'+$(item).text()+'</div>' 
  }
  else
  {
    firstOption+='<div class="item" data-value="'+$(item).val()+'">'+$(item).text()+'</div>'
  }
})
html+=firstOption;
html+=remainingOptions;
html+='</div></div>'

$('#datadiv').html(html)
```

[**See working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoj/965czyq7/)

Comment: Almost close to what I expected :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. The function would look like so

```
function(anyID){
    let $selectElem = $(`#${anyID}`),
      $options = $selectElem.find('options'),
      $firstOption = $options.splice(0,1),
      $div = $('<div></div>'),
      $contentDiv = $div.clone().addClass('content'),
      $containerDiv = $div.clone().attr('id', anyID),
      $firstDiv = createDivFromOption($firstOption).addClass('default text');

    $containerDiv.append( $firstDiv )
               .append( $contentDiv );

    $options.each(index => {
      let $option = $(this);
      createDivFromOption($option).appendTo($contentDiv);
    });

    function createDivFromOption($option){
      let value = $option.attr('value'),
          text = $option.html();

      return $div.clone()
                .addClass('item')
                .attr('data-value', value)
                .html(text);
   }
}
```